# Getting data from child select box in parent using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component with a select form element, this queries my API and makes a select box out of the data. I then try to pass the option back that's been selected via an OnChange function to my parent component so I can then send my data back to the server. I keep getting an error saying state is not defined, I am new to react and can't see where I am going wrong.

Here is my parent component

```
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
const uuid = require('uuid/v1');
import {postDataTest} from "../actions/postData";
import TeamSelectBox from "./TeamSelectBox";
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from "react";

class PlayerForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                teamId: ''
            };
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        }


    fieldValues = {
        name: null,
        teamName: null,
        bio: null
    }

    handleChange(dataFromChild) {
        console.log(dataFromChild);
    }

    nextStep(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get values via this.refs
        var player = {
            id: uuid(),
            name: ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.name).value,
            teamName: ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.teamName).value,
            bio: ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.bio).value,
            teamId: ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.teamId).value
         };

         postDataTest(player);
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6">
                <div className="panel">
                    <div className="panel-heading">
                        <h1>Add Player</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <form className="form-horizontal">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label className="control-label">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="name" defaultValue={this.fieldValues.name}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label className="control-label">Team Name</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="teamName" defaultValue={this.fieldValues.teamName}/>
                            </div>
                            <TeamSelectBox state={this.state.teamId} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label className="control-label">Bio</label>
                                <input type="textarea" className="form-control" ref="bio" defaultValue={this.fieldValues.bio}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="bs-component">
                                 <button className="btn btn-md btn-default btn-block" onClick={this.nextStep}>Save &amp; Continue</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = PlayerForm;
```

And here is my child form select box

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {postDataTest} from '../actions/postData';

class TeamSelectBox extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            teams: []
        };
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("/api/teams")
            .then(response => {
                const teams = response.data;
                this.setState({teams});
                console.log(teams);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="form-group">
                <label for="inputSelect" className="control-label">Select Team</label>
                <div className="bs-component">
                    <select value={this.probs.state.teamId} onChange={this.probs.onChange} className="form-control">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    {this.state.teams.map(singleTeam =>
                        <option value={singleTeam.id}>{singleTeam.team.name}</option>
                    )}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default TeamSelectBox;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems OK, but you had a typo in your child Component:

```
{this.probs.onChange}
```

change it to `{this.props.onChange}` and try again!

Comment: Ah don't know how I didn't see that thank you, to then send the teamId back can I set it in my player object like teamId: this.state.teamId; ?

Answer (score 1):

i think you have a typo, you missed spell props, `this.props` not `this.probs`